# Haskell efficient concatenation of lists

Tags: list, haskell, concatenation

When I have a function

```
func :: Int -> Int -> [[a]]
func a b = func' a ++ func' b
```

where

```
func' :: Int -> [[a]],
```

what is a good possibility to avoid the (++)?

Comment: What's wrong with using the concatenation operator?

Comment: I want a more efficient way, from the perspective of complexity.

Comment: `(++)` is as good as it gets, for lists.

Comment: what is the complexity of ++ in haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) is an alternative to lists which has many operation implemented efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general "difference list" technique for `(++)` elimination by rewriting a function to use extra argument such that `f a b == g a ++ b`.

You can see it used e.g. in

- [all possibilities of dividing a list in two in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178437/all-possibilities-of-dividing-a-list-in-two-in-haskell/15179576#15179576)
- [is it possible to do quicksort of a list with only one passing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641936/is-it-possible-to-do-quicksort-of-a-list-with-only-one-passing/9550430#9550430)

In your case this means rewriting `func` to incorporate the `func'` functionality by essentially inlining the `(++)`, e.g.:

```
func :: Int -> Int -> [[a]]
func a b = go a 1 where 
  go _ _ = _ : _
  go _ _ = _ : _            -- replicate func' code, except
  go _ 1 = {- [] -} go b 0  -- the base case 
  go _ 0 = []
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to List, you can use join (`>>=`) like so: `func a b = [a, b] >>= func'`.

Comment: I didn't notice the comment about complexity. With lazy evaluation neither (++) nor >>= are costly.