# All ways of dividing an array (element combinations) into a custom partition

Tags: javascript, algorithm, grouping, combinations, combinatorics

I want to divide array of n elements to given size subarrays with all possible combinations of elements.

For instance:

Array: `{1,2,3,4}` - can be n elements, 1 < n < 100. It can have duplicates.

Given size pattern (just example, could be different): `[2 -subarrays, 2-elements]`

Expected result:

> {1,2},{3,4}
>   {1,3},{2,4}
>   {1,4},{2,3}

or

> {2,1},{3,4}
>   {1,3},{4,2}
>   {3,2},{1,4}

etc.. As You can see, the order of elements in subarrays, or the order of subarrays in sets of subarrays does not matter. It has to be minimum number of sets of the input array subarrays.

I've got to below solution, but it includes also permutations. I need to optimize this to not generate any permutations at all. JavaScript is not necesarry, any language will do. Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
function getN(n, array, subsets) {
    var f,
        l = array.length,
        indices = [],
        temp;

    array = array.slice();
    while (l--) {
        f = factorial(l);
        indices.push(Math.floor(n / f));
        n %= f;
    }
    temp = indices.map(i => array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
    return subsets
        ? subsets.map((i => l => temp.slice(i, i += l))(0))
        : temp;


}

function factorial(num) {
    var result = 1;
    while (num) {
        result *= num;
        num--;
    }
    return result;
}

var i, l,
    array = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    subsets = [2, 2],
    pre = document.getElementById('out');

for (i = 0, l = factorial(array.length); i < l; i++) {
    pre.innerHTML += i.toString().padStart(4) +': ' + JSON.stringify(getN(i, array, subsets)) + '\n';
}
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: An easy (but not optimized) solution would be to remove permutations from the result array.

Comment: Yes I know, but i'm looking for fast optimized solution, not generating permutations.

Comment: What is the constraints?

Comment: Pham Trung, what do You mean by constraints?

Comment: What I means is how large the size of the array should be? and the size pattern?

Comment: With array size `n`, and the pattern size `m`, the number of valid answer will be `n!/(m! ^ (n/m))` , which for example, if `n = 20, and m = 2 -> 20! / 2^10` which is still very large.

Comment: I've edited the question. Array size 1 < n < 100. Size of pattern will fit the size of array. I know it is still very large. But smaller than with permutations.

Comment: Not worth the effort honestly, for n = 100, and m = 100, yeah, there is only one, but a slightly smaller group m = 50 , there are already 1.0089134e+29 unique answers; m = 25, there are 1.6122075e+57 unique answers.

Comment: Is it possible that the input array has duplicates or not?

Comment: Yes, input array can have duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permutations - all possible sets of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506888/permutations-all-possible-sets-of-numbers)

Comment: No, it's not duplicate. It's the opposite of this question. I need to get rid off permutations, not make them.

Comment: @PhamTrung what's more interesting is a division into multiple `m`s. Like [0..9] divided into [[x],[x,x],[x,x,x],[x,x,x,x]]. https://repl.it/@gl_dbrqn/OnerlookedCulturedComputergames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a recursive formulation that will enumerate combinations of actual elements. In the list, `[2,2]`, each `2` is considered a different element. We can enter arbitrary patterns like `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` divided into all combinations with pattern `[[x],[x,x],[x,x,x]]`.

```js
function f(ns, subs){
  if (ns.length != subs.reduce((a,b) => a+b))
    throw new Error('Subset cardinality mismatch');

  function g(i, _subs){
    if (i == ns.length)
      return [_subs];

    let res = [];
    const cardinalities = new Set();

    function h(j){
      let temp = _subs.map(x => x.slice());
      temp[j].push(ns[i]);
      res = res.concat(g(i + 1, temp));
    }

    for (let j=0; j<subs.length; j++){
      if (!_subs[j].length && !cardinalities.has(subs[j])){
        h(j);
        cardinalities.add(subs[j]);

      } else if (_subs[j].length && _subs[j].length < subs[j]){
        h(j);
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
  let _subs = [];
  subs.map(_ => _subs.push([]));

  return g(0, _subs);
}

console.log('\n[0,1,2,3], [2,2]:');
let str = '';
for (let i of f([0,1,2,3], [2,2]))
  str += '\n' + JSON.stringify(i);
console.log(str);

console.log('\n[0,1,2,3], [1,3]:');
str = '';
for (let i of f([0,1,2,3], [1,3]))
  str += '\n' + JSON.stringify(i);
console.log(str);

console.log('\n[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,3,4]:');
str = '';
for (let i of f([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,3,4]))
  str += '\n' + JSON.stringify(i);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Nice solution, I think this is a challenging implementation, so glad to see you have nicely put it :).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want `n` combinations of an array. You may do as follows;

```js
Array.prototype.combinations = function(n){
  return this.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p.concat(n > 1 ? a.slice(i+1).combinations(n-1).map(e => [].concat(e,c))
                                                 : [[c]]),[]);
};

var result = [1,2,3,4].combinations(2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    result = [1,2,3,4,5,6].combinations(3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Unlike my answer, this doesn't allow for arbitrary patterns like [1,2,3,4,5,6] divided into combinations with pattern [[x],[x,x],[x,x,x]].

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm not sure if this actually answers the question at all.