# Filtering lists which have the same number of different elements in them in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I am pretty new to Haskell and I have the data `data Instruction = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Dup | Pop deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Generic)` and I am generating lists with all possible combinations of `Mul` and `Dup` with `mapM (const [Mul, Dup]) [1..n])` of size n.

I wanted only the lists starting with `Dup` and ending with `Mul` so I used `filter((== Mul) . last)(filter((== Dup) . head) (mapM (const [Mul, Dup]) [1..n]))` but I also want only the lists with the same number of `Mul` and `Dup` in them but I can't seem to come up with a way of doing this. How do I filter this and is there a more efficient way of doing this as there may be a huge amount of combinations as lists get bigger?

A sample list would look like this: `[Dup,Mul,Dup,Mul]` and `[Dup,Dup,Mul,Mul]` for lists of size 4.

Comment: I must say, I really like how you do `mapM (const [Mul, Dup]) [1..n]` — that’s a really elegant way of generating those lists, and one which I would not have found myself! Perhaps `sequenceA (replicate 3 [Mul, Dup])` might be a bit easier to read, but I certainly like how you did it.

Comment: @bradrn `replicateM 3 [Mul, Dup]` is also known to work. Still, instead of generating all the lists and then filtering out the wrong ones, it could be faster to generate only the wanted ones in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @chi, somehow I completely forgot about `replicateM`! That is indeed a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your approach is correct, I think it's not the most efficient one. You generate `2^N` lists and then filter out many of them. Forgetting the other requirements to keep the counting simple, by requiring that we have as many `Mul`s as `Dup`s, we end up with only `choose(N, N/2)` lists (the number of subsets of size `N/2` of `1..N`), which is a much smaller figure.

We can instead try to avoid the filtering and generate the wanted lists, only, in the first place. I suggest the following approach, which you can modify as needed to satisfy the other requirements.

We define a function `sameMulDup` which takes two integers `m` and `d` and generates all the lists with `m Mul`s and `d Dup`s.

```
sameMulDup :: Int -> Int -> [[Instruction]]
sameMulDup 0 d = [replicate d Dup]
sameMulDup m 0 = [replicate d Mul]
sameMulDup m d = do
    -- generate the first element
    x <- [Dup, Mul]
    -- compute how many m and d we have left
    let (m', d') = case x of
           Dup -> (m  , d-1)
           Mul -> (m-1, d  )
    -- generate the other elements
    xs <- sameMulDup m' d'
    return (x:xs)
```

Intuitively, if `d=0` or `m=0` there is only one possible list to include in out list-of-lists result. Otherwise, we non deterministically pick the first element, decrement the correponding counter `d` or `m`, and generate the rest.

Alternatively, the last equation can be replaced by the following more basic one:

```
sameMulDup m d =
    map (Dup:) (sameMulDup m (d-1))
    ++
    map (Mul:) (sameMulDup (m-1) d)
```

Anyway, given `sameMuldup`, you should be able to solve your full task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works great for creating lists with the same number of different elements in it. I just need to figure out how to edit it in order to generate only the lists with first element `Dup` and last `Mul`.

Comment: @GeorgiSpasov Subtract 1 from the needed `m` and `d`, then add the two missing elements in their known spot.

Comment: I got nerd sniped hard by the following observation: `sameMulDup` will get called many, many times with the same arguments over the course of a run. For example, after generating the prefixes `Mul:Dup:...` and `Dup:Mul:...`, the two `...` could conceivably be shared but in this implementation will be recomputed. It is fairly straightforward to produce a version that has the suggested sharing, but the nerd snipe is this: is the fully-shared version actually better? Probably if you plan to iterate over the list just once, sharing more is worse, but twice or more and it's better.

Comment: @DanielWagner Nice observation. Indeed it depends on the consumer. In short: dynamic programming considered harmful (well, sometimes at least).

Comment: @chi In ghci or compiled without optimizations, it turns out that the shared version is both faster and less memory hungry! But with `-O2`, it's pretty much as we both guessed. See my answer for full details.

Comment: How do you arrive at your 2^(N/2) figure? I think it should be choose(N, N/2) instead.

Comment: @DanielWagner Oops, you are correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to define a function `countPred :: a -> [a] -> Int`, which counts the number of items in the list which are equal to the first argument; you can then do `filter (\l -> countPred Mul l == countPred Dup l)` (or alternately `filter ((==) <$> countPred Mul <*> countPred Dup)` if you prefer point-free form). Another approach I suppose might be to do `(==0) . sum . map (\case { Mul -> 1, Dup -> (-1) })`, but that strikes me as being slightly more complex than necessary.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This filters the lists perfectly but i will also try to make it more efficient and generate only the lists needed.

Comment: @GeorgiSpasov I suggest that for now you might want to just solve the problem without worrying about efficiency. If you’re worried about that, you can always benchmark it later to try and fine the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 2):

I like chi's answer, but in a comment, I mentioned that it doesn't achieve as much sharing as it could. I speculated that the sharing would be beneficial if you iterate over the list of instructions multiple times, but worse if you iterate just once. Empirically, the sharing version appears to be faster no matter how many times you iterate, but the memory tradeoff is as predicted: worse for one iteration, better for multiple. So I thought it might be interesting to show it.

Here's how it looks. We're going to make an infinite list of answers. The first index will be how long the list of instructions will be; the second is how many `Mul`s there are (though I'll use `True` and `False` instead of `Mul` and `Dup`). So:

```
bits :: [[[[Bool]]]]
bits = iterate extend [[[]]] where
    extend bsss = zipWith (++)
        (map (map (False:)) bsss ++ [[]])
        ([[]] ++ map (map (True:)) bsss)
```

For completeness, here's how you write a function with the same signature as chi's `sameMulDup`, and computing the same answer (up to the swap to `Bool`):

```
sameMulDup' :: Int -> Int -> [[Bool]]
sameMulDup' m d = bits !! (m+d) !! m
```

Some timings on my machine, for `m=d=12`, when compiled `-O2`:

```
sameMulDup , one iteration  1.35s    6480Kb
sameMulDup', one iteration  1.11s  226476Kb
sameMulDup , two iterations 4.26s 2135368Kb
sameMulDup', two iterations 1.97s  620880Kb
```

Here is the driver code I used for acquiring these numbers:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    [sharing, twice, m, d] <- getArgs
    let answer = (if read sharing then sameMulDup' else sameMulDup) (read m) (read d)
    if read twice
       then do
           print . sum . map (sum . map fromEnum) $ answer
           print . sum . map (sum . map (fromEnum . not)) $ answer
        else print . sum . map (sum . map fromEnum) $ answer
```

There are some subtle points here:

1. To iterate over the list twice, we must have a way of referring to the same list in both iterations. This is `answer` in the above code.
2. We must use an iteration that actually forces all the values for it to be useful. I do this by counting up how many `True`s there are, but there are other ways. (Just printing the whole list doesn't work well: the calculation's runtime is then dwarfed by the production of the `String` to print and the work done in transferring it to the terminal.)
3. Although the first iteration uses the same code in both branches of the `if`, it is important that this code not be shared and moved out of the `if`. We want the compiler to know in the `else` branch that `answer` will not be used again, so that it may garbage collect. If you write `print answer >> if twice then print answer else pure ()`, it is not as obvious statically when the prefix of `answer` may be garbage collected.
4. In the `then` branch, I used two different calculations in the two loops, so that the compiler did not attempt to get clever and do the calculation just once and then print the calculated result twice.

Comment: there are two different `sameMulDup`s in chi's answer, which one have you tested this with?

Comment: @WillNess I have now tested with both. At `-O2`, the results are essentially identical with either version.

Comment: it's not clear how exactly you're iterating over the list of results. do you bind it to a variable or use directly somehow? perhaps provide some code snippet to clarify? details could matter.

Comment: @WillNess Does this edit address your concerns?

Comment: yes, thanks. in reality though, if we needed to iterate over such list twice it'd be much preferable to generate it twice as well, to keep the memory usage as low as possible (so, avoid sharing at all costs). that brings this problem to the fore -- it is quite natural to code this thing to run in constant (more or less) memory in an imperative language like C or Lisp, and seems quite impossible to do so in high-level Haskell...  both chi's variants don't seem to achieve that.

Comment: @WillNess Perhaps it would be preferable, perhaps not. There is, as usual, a memory-vs-compute-time tradeoff. I also don't understand your complaint that it is impossible to code this to run in constant-ish memory in Haskell. `sameMulDup` does exactly that -- provided you only iterate over its result once.

Comment: if you run it for n=12, and then for n=16 or something, will the memory usage stay the same? I thought the 7M figure is still too high for that...

Comment: @WillNess Yes, a driver which uses chi's solution to compute 10/10,11/11,12/12,13/13,14/14 in sequence still uses <7M.

Comment: for background, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875763/haskell-running-out-of-memory-with-finite-lists/61896940#61896940) is what I had in mind.