# Prevent list comprehension from accumulating in memory

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, lazy-evaluation

I'd like to work sequentially on a list of digits that follow a particular pattern:

```
99999999999999
99999999999998
...
99999999999991
99999999999989
```

In other words, 14 digits of decreasing numeric value but only using the digits 1 through 9. Each digit is used individually, so the representation as a number is only for convenience.

For this sort of thing I've always used a combination of a list comprehension and `sequence`, like so:

```
ins = let dig = reverse ['1'..'9'] in sequence (replicate 14 dig)
```

and relied on Haskell's laziness to ensure not all 14 trillion elements are created at once. Alas, this is back-firing, since my application is exploding in memory usage. I've whittled it waaaaay down to this MRE:

```hs
run = let ins = let dig = reverse ['1'..'9'] in sequence (replicate 14 dig)
          outs = map (\x -> (x, map digitToInt x)) ins
      in filter isGood outs
  where isGood (_,i) = if sum i == 50 then trace "Found one." True else False
```

My expectation is that `filter isGood outs` would iteratively evaluate an element in `ins`, and discard all those that are not `isGood`. What actually happens is that within a few seconds, the application uses GB of RAM even before a single `isGood` is found, and it keeps rising rapidly until I kill it. I've tried various combinations of `head` and `dropWhile` to try to force thunks to be evaluated and unused results to be discarded, but to no effect. I seem to have narrowed the culprit down to the `sequence` line.

Can this sort of list comprehension be used without keeping all generated results in RAM? Is there another list generation technique (short of a recursive function that calculates the next element based by parsing the current element) I can use that might do better?

---

Full compilable program for reference:

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Char (digitToInt)
import Debug.Trace (trace)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  print run

run = let ins = let dig = reverse ['1'..'9'] in sequence (replicate 14 dig)
          outs = map (\x -> (x, map digitToInt x)) ins
      in filter isGood outs
  where isGood (_,i) = if sum i == 50 then trace "Found one." True else False
```

Comment: Bouyed by the power of the MRE, I gave this a go instead: `ins = filter (notElem '0') (map show [99999999999999,99999999999998..11111111111111])`. Crude, but wow - memory usage hits **2.5MB** and doesn't budge, while execution seems to be much the same. So `sequence` is to be avoided in this case?

Comment: Aside: `[x | x <- xs]` is just `xs`. So you could simplify further to `let digs = sequence $ replicate 14 ['9', '8'..'1']`.

Comment: Oh yeah @amalloy of course! I got wound up in complexity that is entirely unnecessary here. Nice one, that is indeed equivalent, including the memory usage issue! So that narrows it down even further - this isn't a list comprehension issue, per se.

Comment: The `sequence` library function is known to have suboptimal memory requirements when used to make a large Cartesian product. See for example: [SO question 61875763](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875763/haskell-running-out-of-memory-with-finite-lists)

Comment: For those arriving here post closure, note that the question has been edited to remove the list comprehensions so it's a little hard to follow now. But ultimately the list comprehension turns out to be a red herring, and it is indeed `sequence` that accumulates build products. The linked answer explains this nicely as "GHC decides to keep [partial subsequences] around so they don't need to be recomputed each time each time", and my comment above provides a specific workaround for the question here: use a `filter`ed range instead.