# Two subsets with minimum difference

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, subset, dynamic-programming

Consider an array `arr`.

`s1` and `s2` are any two sub sets of our original array `arr`. We should partition our original array such that these two sub sets have the **minimum difference**, i.e., `min(sum(s1) - sum(s2))` where `sum(s1) >= sum(s2)`.

I'm supposed to print these two sub sets, i.e.,  `s1` and `s2`, as my output.

You can store these sub sets in a **vector**.

For example if  `arr[] = [0,1,5,6]`, then the minimal difference is `0` and my  two sub sets are `s1[] = [0,1,5]` and  `s2[] = [6]`.

Another example could be `arr[] = [16,14,13,13,12,10,9,3]`, and the two sub sets would be `s1[]=[16,13,13,3]` and `s2[] = [14,12,10,9]` with a minimum difference of `0` again.

I can't seem to figure out how to get to these two sub sets.

Much appreciated!

**Note:** I know how to obtain the minimum difference from the two sub sets using DP but I am unable to proceed further. It's getting the two sub sets (with the minimal difference) that I'm unable to do.
Just an algorithm with a nudge along the right direction would do.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int min_subset_sum_diff(int a[], int n,int sum) {
    vector<vector<bool>> go(n + 1, vector<bool>(sum + 1, false));
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; ++i) {
        go[i][0] = true;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= sum; ++j) {
            if (a[i - 1] <= j) {
                go[i][j] = go[i - 1][j - a[i - 1]] || go[i - 1][j];
            }
            else {
                go[i][j] = go[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = (sum / 2); j >= 0; --j) {  
        if (go[n][j]) {                  // only need the last row as I need all the elements, which is n
            return sum - 2 * j;
        }
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 3,100,4,4 };
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto i : a) {
        sum += i;
    }
    cout << min_subset_sum_diff(a, n,sum);
}
```

```
s1 = sum(first_subset)

s2= sum(second_subset)
```

Assuming `s2>=s1`,

```
s1 + s2 = sum_arr
s2 = sum_arr - s1       //using this in the next equation
s2-s1 = difference
(sum_arr - s1) - s1 = difference 
sum_arr - 2*s1 = difference
```

This is my underlying logic.

`sum(s1)` and `sum(s2)` lie between `0..sum_arr`

Since I assume `s1 < s2`, s1 can have values only between `0..(sum_arr/2)`

And my aim is to minimum value of `sum_arr - 2*s1`, this will be true for the largest `s1` that is true

Comment: if you know how to get the minimum difference via DP you just need to remember the partionion along with the minimum difference you calculate

Comment: @user123456 Probably because seems likely to be homework, have been asked before, and solutions like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-a-set-into-two-subsets-such-that-the-difference-of-subset-sums-is-minimum/ are an easy Google search away.

Comment: This was actually a technical F2F interview question. And I haven't found any solution that actually partitions the array into two sub arrays. All solutions only output the minimum difference. I did my research before asking it over here.

Comment: @user123456 See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63362010/585411 for my solution to a variant of this problem.  (Find all subsets of fixed size that sum to a given sum.  Without duplicates.) If you can understand the way I used linked lists there, then the solution to this one should be easy.  It will, of course, only output the set that sums to one half, you have to go back and figure out the complement of that set.

Comment: For your simpler problem, I would simply build a lookup from subset sum to the first element of the array which is the last element in a subset giving that sum.  Then use that lookup to find the one set, and calculate its complement for the other.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The request is that the sum of one subset minus the sum of the other is as small as possible.  This is the subset sum problem except actually find the elements.

Comment: You shouldn't ask a question, delete it because you don't like the comments and ask the exact same question one hour later.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I don't understand how that answers my question. If at all I could get the first sub array, then what you've said is obvious. The whole challenge is getting the sub array. Care to explain how you would get the first sub array?

Comment: I don't understand why there are so many down votes. This isn't really an easy question and I haven't found any solution online. Can someone explain to me why they're down voting? Was it how I phrased my question?

Comment: Look at the answer posted by @MBo for a more detailed explanation of one way to do my simpler approach.  I personally will not offer you more help until I see evidence that you've attempted to do something with answers that you've already been given.

Comment: @btilly I understand. I'll try summing everything I've got here and try to come up with something. You've honestly been the only helpful one. I appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: @btilly The updated question cleared up the ambiguity I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Make parallel table of int `T[][]` with the same dimensions as `go[][]`

When you make a decision here

```
if (a[i - 1] <= j)
```

put in `T[i][j]` some kind of information pointing onto `true` precursor coordinates for `go[i][j]`

After filling the tables you search for the best `true` entry in `go[n]` row of boolean table. When it is found, get value from the same cell of `T` table and follow  to precursor, then to precursor of prcursor and so on ("unwind" subset information)